# session management in online exam website using Struts2

Tags: jsp, session, struts2

I am creating online Assessment application using Struts2, JSP and hibernate.

All application parts are running perfectly.

My application is using the concept of session to maintain the state of user who is giving the exam. , since in case browser shut down, system crash i do not want my user should start from the 1st question. Infact, i want my user should start from where he left. Now i am not able to think on this. How to test this. Is there any easy way so that i can simply test my concept.

BY MISTAKE USER CLOSE THE BROWSER, SO WHEN HE RETURN BACK HE/SHE WILL START THE EXAM FROM WHERE HE/SHE LEFT.

he just have to enter the url> enter his exam id> continue the exam.

For this, I am using tomcat server session persistency using JDBC store. I am able to store session object in database table with session ID.

When I reopen the browser, I am able to get session id but not able to get data. My application is showing NullPointerException.

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{
private String candidateID;
private List loadDropDown;
//getter setter methods
public String user_page1() throws IOException{
//loading examID in drop down list.
loadDropDown=new ArrayList(); 
//getting context object
ServletContext ctx=ServletActionContext.getServletContext(); 
//creating session object
HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(false);
//showing session id
System.out.println("User Page 1 :"+session.getId());
if(session.isNew()){
here if user logging first time then application should be able to create new session object and load fresh data.
}
else
{
application should show them a question where they left
}
...
```

So please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Ravinderpal Singh

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message. The exception comes with a stack trace, telling where the exception happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the approach that uses session persistence. 
If the browser is configured to delete cookies on close or is opened in 'private-browsing' mode then the session id will no longer be existing to be sent to the server!

A better approach would be to track whether a user has initiated any test directly in the database. Similarly the database can be updated whenever the user attempts a question.

On user login a check regarding any pending tests can be done and the user be allowed to continue if or as required.

**Update** : Regarding the exception itself, the stack-trace would indeed help as mentioned by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)